# How can I access the scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Look at my plunker (link below). Don't ask why I use tables, it's unfortunately out of my control.

I have two controllers and I want to access the scope models of MainCtrl in the last box, how can I do this without affecting OtherCtrl? I don't want to nest them.

http://plnkr.co/edit/P4a8Ag

Thanks!
Andreas

Comment: Do you mean accessing the scope in one controller from the other controller without nesting them?

Comment: Yes. I guess I can't have one controller for both boxes without nesting OtherCtrl inside MainCtrl or? ..or if I do nest them, how can I make MainCtrl not affecting OtherCtrl? I don't want to have access to anything from MainCtrl in OtherCtrl and vice versa.

Comment: how about inheritance of controllers? or even better, if data is to be shared, put it in a service.

Comment: I don't want to inherit anything into OtherCtrl. Not sure how to use a Service, must read more about it. Can my MainCtrl update the data in this service and then I'll create another controller for my third box which also have access to this service.

Answer (score 0):

For the code as presented, the quick solution is to use `$rootScope` in the `MainCtrl` rather than its own `$scope`, since your "last box" is currently looking for `name` on `$rootScope`, since it does not have a controller of its own:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.name = 'World';
});
```

But as @EduardGamonal suggested, a service is likely a better solution.

For an example of how two controllers can share data that is stored in a service, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390245/215945