# angular broastcast event controller not ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, publish-subscribe

I have a simple app with a search box and a list of results. The search box has its own controller `SearchCtrl`, and the list of results has another, `DocListCtrl`. The `SearchCtrl` emits an event when the user submits and the `DocListCtrl` listens, and updates the results. It works fine if a user enters a query and submits- However, my problem is when a user copy/pastes a URL such as "/app/search?q=foo"  the search event is broadcast *before* the `DocListCtrl` is ready, and therefore the results are not updated.

So in general, is there a way for one controller to declare a dependency on another? Should I have the `SearchCtrl` persist the data somewhere which the `DocListCtrl` can look on when it finally loads?

Comment: Hi @porfuse. Any reason you're using 2 controllers for this? Couldn't you accomplish with one controller?

Comment: @vin The search ctrl is separate because it will persist in other regions of the app, ex the "detail" view will also have the search form. Also the search ctrl only handles parsing the query and fetching the data from the server, the DocListCtrl handles pagination and a few other things

Comment: Do you even need to broadcast an event? Sounds like the DocListCtrl is a child of the SearchCtrl, can you not get the parent scope and look it up?

Comment: @Neil how can I declare one controller to be a child of another?

Comment: Quoting Mark who's answered already - By default, child scopes prototypically inherit from the parent scope, so you already have access to the parent controller's properties in the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already discovered, an app should not be architected in such a way that the order of controller instantiation matters.  A better approach is to use a service to manage the search results, which can be injected into both controllers.

Example service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390245/215945