# Angular.js Inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've found an example here : http:// jsfiddle.net /HAKASHUN/2DNLH/5/ but he does not work.

I have a controller Post for example. And a controller AdminPost for admins. I don't want to rewrite all the functions in Post in my controller AdminPost.

I know i can create a factory like here : [AngularJS controller inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386137/angularjs-controller-inheritance)

But I think it is not a very good "MVC" organization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of your business logic should reside in a "service/factory." Your controller should then just be a thin layer to call into the "services" Both controllers can then just inject in the service.

Comment: For example If i want to show a loader, i can't put it into a service, right ?

Comment: Look at the source for ui-bootstrap. Great example.