# AngularJS: Controller inheritance using call (or apply)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

This is something I discovered when trying to make my controllers more reusable.

```
app.factory('BaseController', function(myService) {
  return function(variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
    this.method = function() {
      myService.doSomething(variable);
    };
  };
})

.controller("ChildController1", function($scope, BaseController) {
  BaseController.call($scope, "variable1");
})

.controller("ChildController2", function($scope, BaseController) {
  BaseController.call($scope, "variable2");
});
```

And now I can do something like this in my HTML (e.g inside ng-controller="ChildController1"): ng-click="method()"

The code simply works. But I don't know how it really works (what kind of pattern is it?) and would it be a good practice to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works more or less like this:

```
app.factory('mixinBaseController', function(myService) {
  return function (scope, variable) {
    angular.extend(scope, {
      variable: variable;
      method: function() {
        myService.doSomething(variable);
      }
    });
  };
})

.controller("ChildController1", function($scope, mixinBaseController) {
  mixinBaseController($scope, "variable1");
})

.controller("ChildController2", function($scope, mixinBaseController) {
  mixinBaseController($scope, "variable2");
});
```

Can you see? By your `.call($scope, ...)` is just setting the context (`this`) to the real `$scope` and this way the `BaseController` just extends your scope with properties and functions.

This is only to demonstrate how your code works.

To achieve a more JavaScript like inheritance, please see:

- [Can an AngularJS controller inherit from another controller in the same module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-controller-in-the-same-module)
- [AngularJS controller inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386137/angularjs-controller-inheritance)
- [AngularJS Inheritance Patterns](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/)
- [Two Approaches to AngularJS Controller Inheritance](https://www.exratione.com/2013/10/two-approaches-to-angularjs-controller-inheritance/)

You should as well have a look at the ["controllerAs" syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) introduced in AngularJS 1.2. I highly recommend to use `controllerAs`. This also should help to implement inheritance for your controllers.